# Help Needed with LTSpice Multistage Cascode Simulation

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, npn, cascode

I'm using this online calculator to get -50 gain for a cascode amplifier:

https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Cascode/BJT-Cascode-Calculator.phtml

However, I failed to duplicate the value in LTspice. Did I miss out on any setting or model parameter in LTspice?

**My circuit**
[image: My circuit]

**My Output and Gain**
[image: MyOutput and Gain]

Comment: You didn't adhere to the daycounter circuit. RE1 and RE2 appear in that circuit but, in yours, they don't.

Comment: hi @Andyaka Thank you for commenting.. i set RE2 = 0 in the calculator and i already tried with RE2 = 0.004 . same output nothing changed.

Comment: You should read the advice given on the daycounter calculator website and use an RE2 resistor. Loading with 112 ohms requires an output buffer amplifier and significantly smaller base bias resistors.

Comment: @Andyaka hi Andy.. thank you for the advice.. the circuit it just me trying out different option to try and get the gain.. however i already uploaded new circuit with RE2 added.. but the gain are still the same and i cant get it working as the calculation.

Comment: A value for RE2 of 0.004 ohms is ridiculously low and ineffective. You need an output buffer to drive 112 ohms of load if you have any expectations of getting a reliable gain of -50.

Comment: im sorry in still very new on this thing.. just trying to prove the calculation. i will try with higher RE Value.

Comment: what value should i edit to effciently increase the gain?

Comment: You need a buffer amplifier to get a gain of -50 into a load of 112 ohms. I've said this three times now. Please listen.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry i just googled buffer amplifier.. the load can be changeable.. its not fix value.. like i said I'm just trying the calculation value with the ltpsice simulation.. which is not same.. i understand i do some mistakes which im not quite sure.. i tried many range of value different Rl and others but still cant figure out my mistake.

Comment: If the load is changeable then you need a buffer amplifier because the changing load affects the gain of the circuit. Daycounter says this: *It should be noted, that in the real world, for frequencies above 2MHz, a second emitter follower buffer stage is needed to prevent loading of the output stage, and reduced frequency response.* - and this applies to variable load values or load values that are too small for this type of amplifier. 112 ohms is waaaaaaaay too low.

Comment: How did you calculate all the values?, they are not making any sense.  RE1 is only 0.04 ohms or 40 **milli**ohms, that's basically a short circuit and RE2 is even worse. The ratio between RC and RE2 is 175000 not 50.  RC is much higher than RL, it should be the other way around, or you will need a buffer as Andy aka suggested.  And the base bias resistors seem too high for 700 ohms RC.  And CE1 is very low compared to C2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a buffer amplifier with low output impedance if you want to have a variable load impedance. Something like this would work quite well: -

[image]

It has an AC response like this: -

[image]

It's a reasonably flat response from around 100 Hz to about 1 MHz and not too bad given the transistors used. And note that the passband gain is about 34 dB (a gain of fifty).

If you loaded the emitter output with 112 ohms, the gain would reduce a couple of dB to about forty. It's not ideal but it might be good enough for what you want.

Comment: Thank you ! it surely will help with real design application !.. however i tried to design this without any buffer amplifier.. and with much higher RLoad.. can it be done? i tried to use the same formula as the website without changing much of it..

Comment: A much higher load resistance helps a lot but, use the values I gave above and take your output from Q1's collector.

Comment: Thank you! will try it

Comment: @KiraYamato I think you need a refresher on what this site is about and what drives the motivation for people giving free help: [take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out why I helped you.